# Search results don't show products

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, search

my website is a woocommerce site and it has blog posts and some pages. My problem is the search box. Everytime I searched it only shows the posts and pages results. It is not showing woocommerce products. How can I fix this wordpress search result?

Here is my wordpress search.php

https://pastebin.com/SQqihtd0

Answer (score 1):

You have in your query `WHERE p.post_type IN  ('post', 'page')`, that is why  it shows only the posts and pages. Add post type **product** to query:
`WHERE p.post_type IN  ('post', 'page', 'product')`

Comment: Wow thanks! It works. Last question, it shows big images on search. How can I edit that?

Comment: Try replace `wp_get_attachment_url` with [**wp_get_attachment_image_src**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) in line 43. You will get array with keys: **url, width, height, is_intermediate**, then `$url_img = $result['url']`.   
Use for example **thumbnail** as size parameter  in `wp_get_attachment_image_src` function.

Comment: Hi, I've added this $url_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src ($attachment_id, $size = '', $icon = false );
$url_img = $result['url']; but it is not showing any image. Just text.

Comment: @Dale `$result = wp_get_attachment_image_src ( get_post_thumbnail_id($row->id), 'thumbnail'); $url_img = $result['url'];`

Comment: still not showing thumbnail or image.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this with your search form and products will show in results:

```
 <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <label for="s">Search</label>
    <input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search Something" />
    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" id="post_type" value="product"  />
</form>
```